# Difference in AIC and BIC values between sem and lavaan packages in R

Tags: r, aic, structural-equation-modeling, bic, lavaan

I ran the same SEM model in `sem` and `lavaan`. I got the same parameters and,  generally, very close test values, with the exception of `AIC` and `BIC` which were immensely different between the two packages.

The following is the resulting `AIC` and `BIC` from `sem`:

```
AIC =  2913.849
BIC =  -1777.617
```

The following is the resulting `AIC` and `BIC` from `lavaan`:

```
Akaike (AIC)                               37780.878
Bayesian (BIC)                             38178.999
```

Why is there such a huge difference in these values? Are they calculated differently in each package?

## edit:

Here are pieces of code on how I got such values.

In the case of package `sem`, I used the following line:

```
options(fit.indices = c("GFI", "AGFI", "RMSEA", "NFI", "NNFI", "CFI", "RNI", "IFI", "SRMR", "AIC", "AICc", "BIC", "CAIC"))
fit = sem(mymodel, cov(mydata), nrow(mydata), data = mydata)
summary(fit)
```

As for the package `lavaan`, the following line was used instead:

```
fit = sem(mymodel, data = mydata, estimator = "ML")
summary(fit,fit.measures=TRUE)
```

I am using `R` version 3.0.3 (2014-03-06) "Warm Puppy" (x64 version), `sem` package version 3.1-3 and `lavaan` package version 0.5-16 .

Comment: Could you append a small piece of code showcasing how you got these numbers? As this is could be a bug do not omit the package versions you are using (as well as R obviously).

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17174/a-problem-with-two-ways-of-calculating-aic) and the answer by Rob.

Comment: +1 to above. different packages (and sometimes even different commands in the same program) calculate AIC differently. Annoying.

Comment: @usεr11852 I edited and included my code lines and versions.. I don't know if you'd also like to see the 'mymodel' variables.

Comment: @Stat: thank you, I'll check it out at the moment!

Answer (score 2):

I suspected the same thing as `Stat` when I wrote my comment but I wanted to cross-check it before saying it and be sure which package does what. This is what takes place:

On the one hand `lavaan` uses the classical definition of $AIC$ as $AIC = -2L(\theta) +2k$ where $k$ is your number of free parameters and $L(\theta)$ the value of the log-likelihood function at $\theta$. (I think this is the "proper" thing to do.)

On the other hand `sem` one uses the approximation $AIC \approx \chi^2 + m(m + 1) - 2DF$ where $m$ is the number of variables in the model and $DF$ is the model's degrees of freedom. This is approximation omits the constant part of the log-likelihood exactly because during model comparison this part is irrelevant. It is essentially a reformulation of the  residual sum of squares - based derivation of $AIC$ for Gaussian likelihoods.

Both $AIC$ values should be immediately available by simply writing out the formulas shown above and replacing each variable with the realization of it in your respective model. (Model summaries have this information.)